# select2 load preassigned values and make them locked

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

Plugin used: [select2](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/)

I have this code to load the assigned_users array into [select2](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/) list but i cant figure out how to lock each value that was loaded so they cannot be removed.

```
$.each(assignedusers2, function(i) {
    $("#assigned_users").select2("val").concat(assignedusers2[i]));
});
```

in Select2 docs it says to lock add `lock: true` to each like so: `{ id: 'user0', text: 'Disabled User', locked: true}` ... is there a way to insert 'locked: true' to the data array for each select2 data value

Comment: From what I understand, you have a list of users and some users were already selected and you want to lock those users, is this correct? If so, I believe your data is comming from the server so why don't you set `locked` in the server and then return the json?

Comment: @milz Yes i could do it that way but i thought there was another way with jquery.. thanks

Comment: @milz Actually...its not that easy from json server data...my server data returns about 200 users and my code will take the "assigned_users" for that particular event and only choose the 3 or 4 assigned users instead of all 200...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you want to load the users from the server and then want to lock a selection of those users. Besides this you want the possibility to add new users to the selection.

If this is the case, you can accomplish that by using the following code:

```
$("#assigned_users").select2({
    multiple: true,
    data:[
        {id: "User-1", text: "User-1"},
        {id: "User-2", text: "User-2"},
        {id: "User-3", text: "User-3"},
        {id: "User-4", text: "User-4"}
    ]
});

var assignedusers = "User-1,User-3";
var assignedusers2 = assignedusers.split(',');

var assignednew = [];

$.each(assignedusers2, function(i) {
    // push it to the array. Otherwise you'll only have the last one
    assignednew.push({id:assignedusers2[i], text:assignedusers2[i], locked:true});
});

$("#assigned_users").select2('data', assignednew);
```

Check [**this jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/milz/qpfa52db/5/) for a working example.

Comment: I already know how to do it that way.. i showed that in my question... but how can I add "locked: true" to my $("#assigned_users").select2("val").concat(assignedusers2[i])); code ?

Comment: What is `assignedusers2`? Please post a sample code. Why are you using `$.each` instead of `...select2('data', assignedusers2)`?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/qpfa52db/2/     assignedusers2 is a string from sql database in format like: "user1,user2,user3...etc"

Comment: [**Here's**](http://jsfiddle.net/milz/qpfa52db/5/) the updated fiddle. Two issues with your code: `array()` is not defined and I've used `[]`. Also, use `.push()`.